# Check if computer is 64-bit or 32-bit without hard drive

Tags: windows, 64-bit

I am fixing a desktop computer for someone and need to reinstall Windows. I need to know whether to install 64-bit or 32-bit Windows. They accidentally formatted the hard drive.

Normally I would just go into the hard drive and search for a `Program Files (x86)` folder as described [**here**](https://superuser.com/a/444013), but clearly that will not work in this situation.

So, is there a way, possibly with a Linux Live CD or maybe by just looking at the processor / motherboard, to tell if the computer supports 64-bit?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can look up if the processor supports X64 or X86-64 by googling the processor model. It'll be a feature listed in the spec sheet.

If you boot the system with a linux live CD, then:

```
grep flags /proc/cpuinfo | grep lm
```

If you get any output, then the system supports *Long Mode*, or 64-bit addresses.

Answer (score 2):

If you try to boot off the 64-bit Windows installation disc, it will either succeed or fail to boot.  If it fails, install 32-bit Windows.

Answer (score 0):

It should be easy to tell by find by looking up the processor.

Some CPUs such as Core iX are all x64, others such as Pentium 4 can be a little bit more tricky and you will need to know the exact CPU model, which should be visible via the bios.

Comment: ^That would probably be easiest vs. pulling the cpu cooler or having to boot anything else.  Intel's ARK site: for when you have the model (assuming intel) http://ark.intel.com/